# WP website changes and cookies

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I did some changes in my website, but I can't see them with my main browser. In incognito mode everything is fine, new changes. Any ideas how to make from website cookies refresh? Or every time I need to delete all data from browser just to see changes?

Comment: Please describe what kind of changes you have made and if you think it's related to cookie, you should include supporting details that made you think so. Webpages don't get stored in cookies. They are stored in cache.

Comment: I changed colors of some circles.

Comment: That feels like some changes with css within the theme. External files referenced from within the page might need to be refreshed twice and if it doesn't work still, try Ctrl + F5 which will forces a cache refresh.